# Circle Inscribing and Circumscribing a regular polygon

Tags: trigonometry

If $\ I_n$ is the area of n sided regular polygon inscribed in a circle of unit radius and $\ O_n$ be the area of the polygon circumscribing the given circle, prove that
$$ \ I_n = \frac{\ O_n (1+\sqrt(1-(\frac{2\ I_n}{n})^2))}{2}$$

Comment: Well, at least give it a try.

Comment: I tried but not able to approach

Comment: Problem is that $\ I_n$ term is inside square it. I also tried to put n=3 and then tried to find $\ O_n$ and $\ I_n$ in terms of Incircle and Circumcircle but not able to prove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's better to give hints:

> You don't need to focus on the complete picture. You need to calculate $\frac{I_n}{O_n}$.

Another:

> Draw a isosceles triangle with the angle between the equal sides being $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$

Last hint:

> Translate the condition of inscrumization and circumization in terms of that isosceles trinagle, and use pythagorus.